# AJAX: Display different SQL queries

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been developing a site for a family member for months now and for the past month have been stuck on the function of the site that filters SQL results.

Here is the page I am working on: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.php

I am just trying to let my users filter the PHP + MySQL results listed on the right of the page with the form to the left of the page.

So here is my current setup:

I connect to the database and table that contains all of the vehicle data on the site using this PHP:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=","","");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to the database.";
    exit;
}
?>
I then have another file that includes all of my SQL queries:
<?php
include('database.php');
try {
  $results = $db->query("SELECT Make, Model, Colour, FuelType, Year, Mileage, Bodytype, Doors, Variant, EngineSize, Price, Transmission, PictureRefs, ServiceHistory, PreviousOwners, Options, FourWheelDrive FROM import ORDER BY Make ASC");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error.";
  exit;
}

try {
  $filterres = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT Make FROM import ORDER BY Make ASC");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error.";
  exit;
}
?>
```

The first query is used for the listing results when all rows are displayed in the table.

The second query is used for the 'Make' select element in the form, it simply displays all of the 'Make's' that are displayed in the table and does not show duplicated.

I then have the block of HTML and PHP that echos the results:

```
<?php include('db-affinity/filter.php'); ?>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
      <?php while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
      echo '
        <div class="listing-container ' . $row["Make"] . '">
          <a href="carpage.php"><h3 class="model-listing-title clearfix">'.$row["Make"].' '.$row["Model"].' '.$row["Variant"].'</h3></a>
          <h3 class="price-listing">£'.number_format($row['Price']).'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-container-spec">
         <img src="'.(explode(',', $row["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" class="stock-img-finder"/>
          <div class="ul-listing-container">
            <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul">
              <li class="diesel-svg list-svg">'.$row["FuelType"].'</li>
              <li class="saloon-svg list-svg">'.$row["Bodytype"].'</li>
              <li class="gear-svg list-svg">'.$row["Transmission"].'</li>
              <li class="color-svg list-svg">'.$row["Colour"].'</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style checked-btn hover-listing-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> History checked 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style more-details-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> More details 
          </button>
          <button href="#" class="btn h4-style test-drive-btn hover-listing-btn tst-mre-btn"><span class="test-drive-glyph"></span> Test drive 
          </button>
          <h4 class="h4-style listing-photos-count"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 5 More photos</h4>
        </div>
          ';
      } ?>
```

As you can see it echo's out all of the rows using a while loop in the template.

Last but not least I have my form:

```
<div class="container con-col-listing">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <form class="car-finder-container dflt-container">
         <h2 class="h2-finder">Car finder</h2>
         <ul class="toggle-view">
           <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Make<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <select class="form-control select-box">
                 <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $filterres->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'. $make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
             </select>
             <select class="form-control last-select select-box">
                 <option value="model-any">Model (Any)</option>
                 <option value="two">Two</option>
                 <option value="three">Three</option>
                 <option value="four">Four</option>
                 <option value="five">Five</option>
             </select>
            </div>
           </li>
           <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Body type<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <input id="four-by-four-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="four-by-four-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">4x4</label>
             <input id="convertible-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="convertible-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Convertible</label>
             <input id="coupe-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="coupe-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Coupe</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Transmission<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <input id="automatic-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="automatic-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Automatic</label>
             <input id="manual-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="manual-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Manual</label>
             <input id="semi-auto-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="semi-auto-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Semi automatic</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
         <button href="#" class="btn btn-block car-search-button btn-lg btn-success"><span class="glyphicon car-search-g glyphicon-search"></span> Search cars 
         </button>
         <h4 class="h4-finder"><a href="#">Try our Smart Search </a><span class="glyphicon info-car-search-g glyphicon-info-sign"></span></h4>
       </form>
      </div>
```

You only need to look at the top of the form as the rest isn't relevant, it's basically using the query from code block 2 to display all of the makes into the select element and uses a while loop once again to put every make in the vehicle SQL table.

So down to my question... how can I use AJAX to display only the rows in my SQL table that include the 'Make' that has been selected in my form?

If anyone could take some time to show me an example that would work with my setup that would be great, I am only familiar with PHP and have been struggling to understand how I can use AJAX in my situation, I just need a nice simple way to update the listing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$make = $_POST['make']; //or $_GET if that's how you roll
$query = "
    SELECT make, model, etc.
    FROM myTable
    WHERE make = '$make'
";
```

That will only display results where the make is the selected. You can repeat for the rest of your selection filters with the values from the `POST`ed HTML form. AJAX call might look something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/php/script",
    data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(resp) {
        var response = JSON.parse(resp);
        //code to output to table goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you start off displaying everything. So, instead of issuing an AJAX call for a result set that contains only the makes selected, you may consider just using what you've already displayed and hide the items that don't match the makes. This would simply involve setting `visible=false` on all divs with class that begins with "listing-container", but doesn't match the exact value for the make, which may be "listing-container AUDI".

Something like this:

```
// display only Audi makes
var myContainers = $("div[class^='listing-container ']").not(".listing-container.AUDI");
myContainers.hide();
myContainers.next(".listing-container-spec").hide();
```

The benefit of this is you're not doing another server request. If, however, you're complete set of available vehicles grows so large you don't want to make it possible for the user to list it all on one page (so you pursue pagination), you 'll want to pursue doing an ajax query as you initially considered.

Comment: Hello, I tried using your code however it hides every make for some reason, I am unsure why this is happening. It's currently on the live site.

Comment: I added it to my footer just below the jQuery core, I am still very nooby with js, what do you mean by the "make selection function"?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Can I be really cheeky and ask how I could get this to display whatever the option is in the select element, so for example if BMW is selected then it only shows BMW's?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite similar to what you want to achieve. check it here [Add foreach value to Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494493/add-foreach-value-to-ajax/41496124#41496124)

Comment: if you want to answer its good to explain it, even if a link is attached, i mean a little description would be good.

Comment: Ok @aimme, The example did was creating a copy of data from db of which array representing data from db was structure and documentation was made on how data from db can be structure like that array created, then the data was rendered in a table A and whenever their is selection from table A, table B is filled with d selected item from table A and finally table B data was send asynchronously to a php page (getData.php)  for use for any type of processing that needs to be performed on it. thank you.