# Add foreach value to Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have two questions which are below;
1)How do i pass a value from a foreach to ajax. this is my code and what i have so far, tried putting the ajax inside the foreach but it kept on giving me the id of the last name in the for each.

2)Is there a way that i can click on add and and the data will be held and put in another html table below this html table but wont be inserted into database until i click on insert in the second table.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="table_export">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th><div>Item</div></th>
                        <th><div>Quantity Left</div></th>
                        <th><div>Price</div></th>
                        <th><div>Quantity</div></th>
                        <th><div>Sell</div></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $count = 1; 
                        $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->get_rows_from_field('name');
                        foreach($notarray as $row):?>

                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['nickname'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>

                         <form method="post" action="" role="form">
                        <td>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <div class="">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="kin" data-validate="required" data-message-required="Kin required" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </td>

                            <td>

                            <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name = "check">Add</button>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </form>

                   </tr>

                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <br><br>
            <div id="get_result">
                      </div>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'verify.php',
        data: $('form').serialize() + '&ins=sellin' + '&id=<?php echo $row['name_id'];?>',
         success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#get_result').html(data);
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you mean you wanted to pick an item from list of items in table A and it should display in table B. Afterwards, you wanted to click submit button in table B to save the picked items from Table A?

Here is the solution:

Kindly name this file as `test.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SQ05
 * Date: 06/01/2017
 * Time: 06:31 PM
 */
//Note that data is a typical example of data u gotten from DB. so make sure u push all $row into an array
//such that u create something of this nature eg
// $data=array();
// $i=0;
//while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
//$data[$i]=$row;
//$i++;
//}
// this will then create data of this nature below,
$data=array(
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Loveth','age'=>23,'phone'=>'9889087455'),
    array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Susan','age'=>51,'phone'=>'787987455'),
    array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Precious','age'=>13,'phone'=>'98989087455'),
    array('id'=>4,'name'=>'Hannah','age'=>21,'phone'=>'987087455'),
    array('id'=>5,'name'=>'Kenneth','age'=>43,'phone'=>'569087455'),
);

?>
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
    THE LIST OF ALL ITEMS
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
        $item=$data[$i];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['age'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['phone'];?></td>
            <td><button onclick='addToList(<?php echo json_encode($item);?>);'>Add</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:50%">
  THE ITEM TO BE SAVED
<div id="showToSave"></div>
    </div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> <!--Please install jquery base on ur own directory path-->
<script>
    var listToSave=[]; // must be global

    /**
     * The add to list function that process data and add to list
     * @param data
     */
   var addToList= function(data){
        var lenData=listToSave.length;
          if(lenData>0){
              //this is used to avoid duplicate
             for(var j=0;j<lenData;j++){
                 if(data.id==listToSave[j].id) return;
             }
          }
        listToSave.push(data);
        console.log(listToSave);
        document.getElementById('showToSave').innerHTML=createData(listToSave);

    };

 var createData= function (data) {
        var len=data.length;
     var tableToSave="<table><tr><td>Name</td> <td>Age</td> <td>Phone</td> <td>Action</td></tr>";
     var i;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
          content=data[i];
        tableToSave+="<tr><td>"+content.name+"</td><td>"+content.age+"</td><td>"+content.phone+"</td><td>" +
            "<button onclick='deleteFromSave("+i+")'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
        }
     tableToSave+="</table><div><button onclick='saveData()' type='button'>Save</button></div>";
     return tableToSave;
    };


    /**
     * This is use to delete data added locally
     */
    var deleteFromSave=function (index) {
        listToSave.splice(index,1); //this is use to delete from list to save
        document.getElementById('showToSave').innerHTML=createData(listToSave); //to rerender after delete
    };

    /**
     * This is use to submit data
     */
    var saveData=function () {
        console.log('thjis=',listToSave);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getData.php",
            data: {list : JSON.stringify(listToSave)},
            success: function(resp){
                console.log('response=',resp);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Kindly name this as `getData.php` to process the submission of the list of added data using multiple value insertion approach.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: SQ05
     * Date: 06/01/2017
     * Time: 07:28 PM
     */
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['list'])); //the data here can now be used to create a multiple value insert to ur mysql db.
        print_r(json_encode($data)); // this is used to send response back to ur page if using array buh echo if string
    }
```

Comment: i will write a demo and send probably tomorrow or tonight

Comment: i have provided my solution to that @hamobi

Comment: its working but i cant put more than one item in table b

Comment: Check out the line i commented as  "this is used to avoid duplicate", Kindly make sure the value you are adding to the list is not of the same Id or refactor that line in addToList function to suit what you wanted to do.

Comment: i have already sorted it out before i marked it, what have being trying to do is get the value for the input form with name kin in the for each and add to the item array; The input form seems not to be unique, and when i try to make it unique by attaching the item id to the input form name i get NaN as the result in the array@Casey

Comment: i really don't understand what you are trying to do.. kindly be explicit. you can show the code of what you are trying to accomplish.